# How to delete duplicated lines that have NaN and keep the ones that doesn't

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, for example:

```
   A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0  9   34  1   1   Nan 9   3
1  Nan 34  0   9   Nan 0   2
2  0   8  Nan  3   9   11  0
3  0   8  15   3   9   11  0
4  Nan 6   1   3   Nan  2  3
5  1   6   1   3   44   2  3
```

I want to check which lines have duplicated values in columns B, D and G.
As you can see, lines 2 and 3 have the duplicated values, and so do lines 4 and 5. I have to delete the duplicated lines, but I want to delete the ones that have Nan values (2 and 4).

I've tried the df.dropna() method, but it only has the options

```
 keep = 'last', 
 keep = 'first' or 
 keep='False',
```

and none of these solve my problem.

My expected output is

```
   A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0  9   34  1   1   Nan 9   3
1  Nan 34  0   9   Nan 0   2
3  0   8  15   3   9   11  0
5  1   6   1   3   44   2  3
```

How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: and for lines with Nan that aren't duplicates, do you want to keep them?

Comment: yes!! The only ones that I want to delete are the duplicated

Comment: Whats expected output?

Comment: anywhere! some of them are in pairs, some are not

Comment: I just put the expected output on the question, thanks for reminding me to put it

Comment: Your idea `keep = 'last'` should work with `drop_duplicates()` as i illustrated in my answers however other answer are already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a `pandas` expert but here is one way to achieve this:

```
subset = df[['B', 'D', 'G']]

to_keep = df[~subset.duplicated(keep=False)]

     A   B  C  D    E  F  G
0    9  34  1  1  NaN  9  3
1  NaN  34  0  9  NaN  0  2

to_keep.append(df[subset.duplicated(keep=False)].dropna(), ignore_index=True)

     A   B   C  D    E   F  G
0    9  34   1  1  NaN   9  3
1  NaN  34   0  9  NaN   0  2
2    0   8  15  3    9  11  0
3    1   6   1  3   44   2  3
```

If you want to leave the index as is, drop the `ignore_index` flag

Comment: What does the `~` do?

Comment: it means `bitwise not` so `False` becomes `True` and so forth

Answer (score 1):

You can count nulls by row, sort by this number, then use `drop_duplicates`:

```
df['null_count'] = df.isnull().sum(1)

df = df.sort_values('null_count')\
       .drop_duplicates(['B', 'D', 'G'])\
       .sort_index()

print(df)

     A     B     C    D     E     F    G  null_count
0  9.0  34.0   1.0  1.0   NaN   9.0  3.0           1
1  NaN  34.0   0.0  9.0   NaN   0.0  2.0           2
3  0.0   8.0  15.0  3.0   9.0  11.0  0.0           0
5  1.0   6.0   1.0  3.0  44.0   2.0  3.0           0
```

An alternative if you wish to avoid a helper column:

```
df = df.iloc[df.isnull().sum(1).values.argsort()]\
       .drop_duplicates(['B', 'D', 'G'])\
       .sort_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby with first which returns first not-null value

```
df.groupby(['B', 'D', 'G'], as_index = False, sort = False).first().reindex(columns = df.columns)

    A   B   C       D   E       F   G
0   9.0 34  1.0     1   NaN     9   3
1   NaN 34  0.0     9   NaN     0   2
2   0.0 8   15.0    3   9.0     11  0
3   1.0 6   1.0     3   44.0    2   3
```

Comment: This does not produce the expected output

Comment: @Chris, it does produce expected output apart from the fact that it is resetting the index

Answer (score 0):

You can also use boolean indexing:

```
new = df[df[list('BDG')].duplicated(keep=False)]
df.iloc[~df.index.isin(new[new.isnull().any(1)].index)]

    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0   9   34  1   1   NaN 9   3
1   NaN 34  0   9   NaN 0   2
3   0   8   15  3   9   11  0
5   1   6   1   3   44  2   3
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `drop.duplicates()` using `subset` you can get it done.

`last` : Drop duplicates except for the last occurrence.

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates(subset=['B', 'D', 'G'], keep="last")
     A   B     C  D     E   F  G
0  9.0  34   1.0  1   NaN   9  3
1  NaN  34   0.0  9   NaN   0  2
3  0.0   8  15.0  3   9.0  11  0
5  1.0   6   1.0  3  44.0   2  3
```

Comment: The sample Dataframe happens to have null values in the first row but you can not assume that. Recreate the dataframe by swapping index 4 and 5 and then try the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `&` with conditions `duplicated` and `isnull` for a column-independent way of achieving this

```
>>> to_drop = df.dropna(axis=1).duplicated(keep=False) & df.isnull().any(1)
>>> df.loc[~to_drop]
```